# Is it possible to use IAM roles for ECS tasks in an Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I maintain a project running on Elastic Beanstalk on the [Multicontainer Docker platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html). To securely access the SSM Parameter Store I would like to give specific containers access to specific IAM roles. To minimize unneeded privileges some containers shouldn't have access to these roles at all.

In this configuration Elastic Beanstalk uses the EC2 Container Service for deployment. ECS offers the possibility to specify [IAM roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) in Task Definitions (via the `taskRoleArn` parameter).

I would like to use this ECS feature in EB. Is there a way to customize (or replace) the Task Definitions EB generates? I think it might be possible using a [.ebextensions configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) to customize environment resources but haven't had luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS support this isn't possible at the moment. They raised a feature request though. So it might be possible to set the `taskRoleArn` parameter in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file in the future.

Also, using the Multicontainer Docker platform it's not possible to create or override ECS Task Definitions by using an .ebextensions configuration file.